# 1065 Schedule B - 14, who is a foreign partner?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, limited-liability-company, form-1065

I can't find a solid definition on the IRS website about this. I did find about foreign persons not sure if that applies.

Are people with permanent residency or even tax residency considered foreign partners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to IRS Form 1065 Schedule B question 14.

Foreign partner is defined by [IRC Sec. 1446](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1446):

> **(e) Foreign partner**
>
> For purposes of this section, the term “foreign partner” means any partner who is not a United States person.

"United States Person" is defined by the [IRC Sec. 7701(a)(30)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/7701):

> (A) a citizen or resident of the United States,

Resident, in IRC, refers to tax residency [(IRC Sec. 7701(b))](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/7701).

Comment: Perfect thank you so much!